# rails - What is the biggest security risk in intentionally disabling a CSRF check on the 'create' action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, google-chrome-extension

I have a fully working product on Rails 5. I now wish to make a Chrome extension, using which users can create an 'Article'.

However, requests from my Chrome extension will be treated as Cross Site by my rails app. Hence, I was thinking of not doing the CSRF check at all on *just* my `create` action.

**What is the biggest security risk associated with this?** I understand after this, anyone will be able to make POST request to my server that creates a new article - however, this is not a damaging action like update, or worse, delete.

Comment: So, SPAM is OK? What if it contains malicious links? :}

Comment: Anyway, [not having Anti-]CSRF does *not* mean that 'anyone will make [be able to] make a POST request'. It means that *already authenticated users* could enter state in which their user agent (eg. email, browser, extension) is tricked into making a request with their active authentication without their .. consent. If authentication is disabled, that is a different issue/vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

The Rails guide states that,

> CSRF attack method works by including malicious code or a link in a
>   page that accesses a web application that the user is believed to have
>   authenticated. If the session for that web application has not timed
>   out, an attacker may execute unauthorized commands.

If a CSRF token is a valid one, it is a kind of assurance that the user session has not been hijacked and the request has been made with the user consent.

For more info, I recommend you to refer the Rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Comment: Thank you, but that does not answer my question. I already know what CSRF is and how rails protects against that attack.